# Find each element with attr type without element type

Tags: jquery

I'd like to find each element with an attr of name and replace part of the string.  The caveat is I don't wish to target them by element type.
The below doesn't work:

```
       var index = 0;
       $('.foil').each(function () {
            $(this).each(function () {
                attr = $(this).attr('name');
                if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false){
                    console.log(attr);
                    attr.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, '[' + index + ']');
                }
            });
           index++;
       });
```

This was the solution that worked:

```
                $(this).find('[name]').each(function () {  
                    $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
                });
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Add some sample HTML and what you want the result to be.

Comment: You shouldn't have nested `.each()`.

Comment: This question is useless without example HTML and expected output.  It can be quickly shown that the *provided* code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/21f3rm5n/

Comment: What are you doing with `attr.replace(..` are you trying to *change* the name attribute?  As in `$(this).attr($(this).attr("name").replace(...))`?  (or use the relevant overload)   Your question clearly states *"find each element"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selector `[name]` to find any element with the `name` attribute. You can also combine this with the class selector.

You can give a function to the `.attr()` method, it will automatically execute it for each matching element, so you don't need `.each()`.

There's no need for nested `.each()`. You just need to iterate over the elements once.

```js
$(".foil[name]").attr("name", function(i, name) {
    return name.replace(/\[.*\]/, '[' + i + ']');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="foil" type="text" name="txtfield[23]" />
<input class="foil" type="text" name="txtfield[60]" />
<input class="foil" type="text">
```

If you inspect the input elements, you'll see that they're changed to:

```
    <input class="foil" type="text" name="txtfield[0]" />
    <input class="foil" type="text" name="txtfield[1]" />
    <input class="foil" type="text">
```

Comment: Good starting point! But I think the variable `index` still requires a little TLC ... Maybe it was meant as a sequential number?

Comment: I updated the code to include the outer section for more context.  The Index is an outer counter.  When I tried this, this did not find any attributes (there are several in .foil).

Comment: This worked, however, needed to add .find('[name]').

Comment: That's only needed if the elements you want to change are nested inside the selected elements, not the same elements.

Comment: Since you were using `.each()`, you weren't searching for nested elements.

Answer (score 1):

Consider fthe following code.

```
$(".foil").each(function (i, el) {
  if($(el).attr("name") != undefined || $(el).attr("name") != ""){
    $(el).attr("name", $(el).attr("name").replace(/\[(.?)\]/, "[" + i + "]"));
  }
});
```

So if you have:

```
<input class="foil" type="text" name="txtfield[23]" />
<input class="foil" type="text" name="txtfield[60]" />
```

Each would be iterated and and the `name` attribute would be updated with the new Indexes.

```
<input class="foil" type="text" name="txtfield[0]" />
<input class="foil" type="text" name="txtfield[1]" />
```